# Can DNS nameservers be configured in a shared gitlab CI runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci, vpn

I'm attempting to deploy to a Kubernetes cluster in AWS EKS which lives within private subnets, the deployment is running in Gitlab CI within a shared runner. I've been able to connect to the cluster using `openvpn`, but it seems that the `update-resolv-conf` step of the `openvpn` connection (which is configured) is not occurring. The contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` do not change when the VPN tunnel is initiated. Moreover, I am unable to set the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` within the CI session.

I understand that it would be possible to set the nameservers while standing up my own (private) runners, but I would like to avoid that inconvenience and expense (if possible). Is it possible to set the DNS nameservers on a Gitlab shared runner during execution of the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out how to set a DNS nameserver in the gitlab runner runspace, but I have worked out a (somewhat hacky) workaround to my particular problem in light of the fact that I have access to the DNS servers and that `dig` allows for overriding the configured system nameservers. The plan goes like this: use `awk` to extract the hostname of my k8s management endpoint from `.kube/config`, use `dig` to get an IP address associated with the hostname, then use `sed` to swap the two. Here's what I've got.

```yaml
deploy-app:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    ...
    - cat /root/.kube/config
    - |
      SERVER_NAME=$(grep -m 1 "server: http"  /root/.kube/config | awk -F / ' { print $NF } ')
    - echo $SERVER_NAME
    - SERVER_IP=$(dig @<DNS_SERVER_IP> $SERVER_NAME | grep -A 1 ";; ANSWER SECTION:" | tail -1  | awk ' { print $NF } ')
    - echo $SERVER_IP
    - |
      sed -i --regexp-extended "s/(.*server: https:\/\/).*/\1${SERVER_IP}/" /root/.kube/config
    - cat /root/.kube/config
    ...
```

Take note that Gitlab CI doesn't like it when you use a colon followed by a space in a command (e.g. `server: http`); the pipe-newline mitigates that issue.

I would still love to be able to specify the nameservers in the runner, but this solves my immediate problem with some hacks that will confuse everyone else who reads this CI file and it avoids having to deploy my own runners. Qualified win.